# How to remove duplicate in database

Tags: python, django

The problem is that all fields gets duplicated, i want to achieve just a single field for all product in order. I tried using .distinct(), it is not working. You can see photos;
[image]

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    billing_address = models.ForeignKey('BillingAddress', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    payment = models.ForeignKey('Payment', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='payment_opt')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


def orders(request):
    order = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user.id, ordered=True).distinct()
    context = {
        'order': order,
    }
    return render(request, 'orders.html', context)


{% for order in order %}
<p class="text-muted my-2" style="font-size:14px">
Address: {{ order.billing_address.street_address|capfirst }}</p>
<p class="text-muted my-2" style="font-size:14px"> 
Apartment Address: {{ order.billing_address.apartment_address|capfirst }}</p>
<p class="text-muted my-2" style="font-size:14px"> City: {{ order.billing_address.city|capfirst }} 
</p>
<p class="text-muted my-2" style="font-size:14px"> State: {{ order.billing_address.state|capfirst }} 
</p>
<p class="text-muted" style="font-size:14px"> 
Country: {{ order.billing_address.country.name|capfirst }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `.distinct()` will give you different object (so with a different `pk`), but here your problem is that apparently you have multiple equivalent `Order`s in the database. I strongly advice to fix the problem "upstream", and thus take a look where these "duplicates" are generated.

Comment: @Willem... i still find this difficult to solve. i have tried different code and still not worked. Do you have any to help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Willem pointed out correctly it is normally impossible to have real duplicates when querying a single model like you are doing. So distinct() does not change anything in your query as all objects are distinct (due to pk)

The question is what you consider as a duplicate. What you could do is to use `distinct` on `values`. For instance if you only want a distinct line per user and billing address you could do

```
result = Order.objects.values('billing_address', 'user').distinct()
```

result would be a queryset containing `dicts` with two keys: 'billing_address' and 'user' and the values of the dict being the `pk` of the `BillingAddress` and `User` objects.

As you probably need the actually values and not the pks in your template combine the query above with loopups like so

```
result = Order.objects.values('billing_address__street_address', 'billing_address__apartment_address', 'user').distinct()
```

There are some caveats to this as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct). It is also mentioned there that on PostgreSQL only you can add the fields as arguments directly to `distinct()` but I have neither tried this nor have you mentioned your database